# Delete the space below the header in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm preparing my resume and I need more space to get it done. I want to delete the space bellow the header (in red) and reduce the space between sections and paragraphs

[image: moderncv]

My code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{geometry}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\firstname {Name}
\lastname {LastName}
\title {Job}
\address{Adress}{Adress}
\mobile {123456}
%\phone {number}
\email {a@b.c}
\social[linkedin][link]{name}
%\homepage {link}
%\extrainfo {}
\photo[70pt][0.6pt]{maphoto}
\quote {}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-20mm}

\section{Formation}
\cventry{2015--2017}{Text}{}{}{}{Text.}
\cventry{2012--2015}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}
\cventry{2008--2012}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}

\section{Expériences professionnelles}
\cventry{Juin 2016}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}

\section{Projets académiques}
\cventry{Jan 2016 - Mai 2016}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code of a (reduced) document that containts the preamble, some header resembling yours as well as some sections. We need to know the options that you use as well as the formatting instructions (like sectioning commands). Please make the document compilable.

Comment: I figured out that I can use the \vspace*{-20mm} to reduce the space between the header and the body though. It works

Comment: I still need to reduce the vertical space between the name and the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to remove even more space from the header. Add the following lines:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{1.25em}{0em}{}{}% <<<<< 0em = space between name and title
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead
  {\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}%
  {\raisebox{-1.6cm}{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}% <<<<< -1.6cm: modify to align the image with the rest
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-40mm}% <<<< modify to adjust the distance between title and contents
```

Adjust the three numbers marked above as needed. Note that this is really a hack that may stop working with the next version of `moderncv`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{geometry}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\firstname {Name}
\lastname {LastName}
\title {Job}
\address{Adress}{Adress}
\mobile {123456}
%\phone {number}
\email {a@b.c}
\social[linkedin][link]{name}
%\homepage {link}
%\extrainfo {}
\photo[70pt][0.6pt]{example-image}
\quote {}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{1.25em}{0em}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead
  {\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}%
  {\raisebox{-1.6cm}{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-40mm}

\section{Formation}
\cventry{2015--2017}{Text}{}{}{}{Text.}
\cventry{2012--2015}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}
\cventry{2008--2012}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}

\section{Expériences professionnelles}
\cventry{Juin 2016}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}

\section{Projets académiques}
\cventry{Jan 2016 - Mai 2016}{Text}{}{}{}{Text}
\end{document}
```